# File Name From MySQL Field Value

Tags: php, mysql, file, pdf, header

I have a value from a row in MySQL called ($)lesson_title... I want this value to be the file name for a PDF file generated by FPDF sent by the header instead of a generic file name. Here is what the header in the pdf.php file currently sends:

```
/*
 *  Write PDF content to file.
 */
$pdf->Output($lessonPlanFile, 'F') ;
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="My_Lesson_Plan.pdf"');
```

Where "My_Lesson_Plan.pdf" should be the value of $lesson_title

Sounds simple enough and I've tried quite a few things but can't get the syntax right. =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$lesson_title.'"');
```

More info on string interpolation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php